# angular web app - include library licenses

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I have an angular-cli with many libraries. To include the licenses for these I include all of the `LICENSE` and `package.json` files from `node_modules` in the build.

```
"assets": [
    {
        "glob": "**/package.json",
        "input": "../node_modules/",
        "output": "./licenses"
    },
    {
        "glob": "**/LICENSE*",
        "input": "../node_modules/",
        "output": "./licenses"
    }
]
```

However this adds ~4000 individual files to the output and adds time to the build and upload, and some of the libraries are build/development tools not used in the source. I'm about to zip the licenses in a pre-build process as a quick solution.

This seems like a common issue. Is there a smart tool for this, that packages in a way, only the used licenses?

Comment: Is there a reason why the license list cannot be static?

Comment: @tyteen4a03 no but I was hoping for a programmatic solution and not a list that has to be maintained, and that introduces room for human error. Me a developer might forget a library and when looking at every library to see what libraries it uses you have to look thouhg all of there source code to see what libs they use.