# Include libraries licenses in production build - angular

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

Our angular app has many dependencies (node_modules) usually licensed under Apache 2.0 or MIT. As far as I understand the licenses - production build is a "derived work" and we have to include copyright notices in it.

I know, that I can copy them by a script or include them in an angular.json file (like this: [angular web app - include library licenses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47578837/angular-web-app-include-library-licenses)), but I was looking for a solution recommended by angular developers. I believe that this problem is very common, but can't find a lot of topics about it.

Maybe we are wrong and angular applications using dependencies do NOT need to include copyright notices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your angular.json file in the configurations section, you can add 'extractLicenses' and set it true for any configuration you want. This will extract all the licenses and add to a single file

Comment: Wow. Thank you. Should I assume this is all I need for fullfiling copyright requerements? Assuming all my licences are compatible with each other.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Yes this should cover your copyright requirements.